# Mac: Menubar in IntelliJ IDEA not responding to clicks

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I just decided to try out IDEA after reading glowing reviews for it from various places. The issue is, while it has focus, IDEA simply won't let me click anything on the menu bar, not even the Apple menu. Switching to another app and clicking the menu bar there works fine. All interface elements inside the IDEA window are clickable. Trying to move focus to the menu with `Ctrl+Fn+F2` does not work either.

The only plugin that I have installed is the IdeaVim plugin, but the problem persists even after disabling it and switching the keymap to "Mac OS X 10.5+".

I'm trying this on IDEA 11.1 CE, OS X Lion and JDK 1.6. A quick Google didn't turn anything up. Has anyone else encountered this problem, or am I just being stupid and not seeing something right in front of my face?

EDIT: I've tried the usual tricks of switching to another program and back to IDEA, and closing and relaunching it, neither of which makes any difference.

Comment: I am running IntelliJ 11 on OS X 10.7.4 with JDK1.6 without problems

Comment: This happens when the focus is not on the main window but on another program. Are you sure the IDEA window has focus? What UI skin are you using? (Settings > Appearance > Look and Feel)

Comment: I'm sure the IDEA window has focus, since typing in IDEA works fine. The Look and Feel is "Mac OS X".

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue with IntelliJ 2019.1.1. For anyone else facing the same, make sure the IDE boot jdk is set to the bundled version. To find this, navigate to the actions menu (Cmd + Shift + A), and look for `Switch Boot JDK`. The selected option should look something like "`<VERSION> boot bundled`".

Comment: I just tried this and my boot JDK was already set to bundled. BUT, just me opening that actions menu and then canceling it fixed all the top level menus that wouldn't open. I had even previously tried a computer restart and even that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the latest Java updates from Apple installed, **Look&Feel** in `Preferences` | `Appearance` should be **Mac OS X**.

Also try to rename IDEA [config/plugins/system](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) folders to start with all the default settings and see if you can still reproduce it.